# external HTTP request without using the answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, http

I'm using jQueryMobile. I want to make a http request but I don't need the answer, since I pretty much know the request will suceed. Problem: the request targets an external server thus I could only use JSONP. But the server doens't support that and simply returns either plain text or valid xml (I can change that with the request url).
How can I make this request without getting errors?

When using jsonp in ajax I receive the error, that there is a syntax error.
When only sending the request as a normal ajax/text/xml request, the server gets not contacted at all. I know this since I'm contacting an sms gateway and don't receive an SMS.

My workaround is currently inserting a new iframe with src of that url and style of display: none; Works fine in Firefox but I doubt this is the (only) solution.

What solutions do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've already implemented the best answer. Let's walk through the constraints:

1. It's a cross-origin request to a server you don't control, so you can't use the various HTML5, Flash, or Java APIs that check for same-origin.
2. That leaves inserting some DOM element that will load a remote resource.
3. You've determined that `<script>` won't do, because the content type is wrong.
4. Similarly, you can't use `<img>`, `<embed>`, or `<object>`, and those would be evil hackish choices even if they worked.

I think `<iframe>` is the only choice left, if you want to make the request from the browser.

Your other choice is to implement an API on your own server that proxies to the remote API. Then you can use XHR to make the request, and you can do full error checking on the client if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing with iframes is that I was concerned it wouldn't be rendered hidden by all browsers and therefor not even loaded. I did a little research after and found out, that hidden iFrames is/was a common trick to inject malicous code into websites. I tested it with Firefox and Safari Mobile on the iPad and it both worked. The iframe was not visible at all but obviously loaded. I received from both attempts each an SMS from the gateway.